# Extract two years from a single string

Tags: r, regex

I have a table and I'm trying to manipulate it to extract year values and put it into a new field in that table.  For example:

**Original Table**

```
Code    Description
A       Acme (1985 - 2002)
B       Coakc (2011 - 2012)
A       Jupiter(11) (2011 - )
C       Capital Management Corporation (2011 - )
D       Diuretics Inc (2011 - )
E       Charter (2011 - )
```

**Desired Result**

```
Code    Description                     Start_Year  End_Year
A       Acme                            1985        2002
B       Coakc                           2011        2012
A       Jupiter(11)                     2011    
C       Capital Management Corporation  2011    
D       Diuretics Inc                   2011       
E       Charter                         2011
```

I was thinking something like:

- For Years, If there are 11 spaces between ( and ) then extract 4 characters right of ( and 4 characters left of )
  else extract 4 characters right of (
- For Description, Left of everything  ( ... But Jupiter(11) throws that off

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse` framework you can do it the following way

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)    
df %>% mutate(Start_year=str_match(Description,"(?<=\\()\\d{4}"),
                End_year=str_match(Description,"\\d{4}(?=\\))"))
```